# How to stop first thread when the second thread is finished in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Is there any way to stop first thread when the second thread is finished?

Example:

```python
from functools import partial

import threading

def run_in_threads(*functions):
    threads=[]

    for function in functions:
        thread=threading.Thread(target=function)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

def __print_infinite_loop(value):
    while True:print(value)

def __print_my_value_n_times(value,n):
    for i in range(n):print(value)

if __name__=="__main__":
    run_in_threads(partial(__print_infinite_loop,"xyz"),partial(__print_my_value_n_times,"123",1000))))))
```

In above axample i run in threads two functions and I have to stop the first thread when the second is finished. I read that it supports by events, but unfortunatly I did not use it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `threading.Event` like this:

```
import functools
import threading

def run_in_threads(*functions):
    threads = []

    for function in functions:
        thread = threading.Thread(target = function)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

def __print_infinite_loop(value, event):
    while not event.is_set():
        print(value)

def __print_my_value_n_times(value, n, event):
    for i in range(n):
        print(value)
    event.set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event = threading.Event()
    infinite_loop = functools.partial(__print_infinite_loop, "xyz", event)
    my_values = functools.partial(__print_my_value_n_times, "123", 10, event)
    run_in_threads(infinite_loop, my_values)
```