# Stop a thread when the function on the other thread has finished python

Tags: python, multithreading, scope

[beginner]I have two functions, one takes the camera feed from a gopro and checks for movement. It does this until the amount of movement is equal to a certain number. The other function plays a song. I am using threading, but when the camera function terminates, the songs function continues. How do I stop the second function when the first stops?

Edit: I realize this is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542276/how-to-stop-first-thread-when-the-second-thread-is-finished-in-python) but I'm not sure I understand what is happening.

Comment: What you need is something (called an "event") that keeps track of whether the song should be playing or not. The thread that's playing the song only plays the song when the song should be playing (when the event is in a particular condition). The thread that counts the movement changes the state of the event when it detects the movement.

Comment: How is the song played? You may be able to close that api from the camera thread. The song playing thread gets an error from the api and knows to exit.

Comment: Another method is a simple flag. Assuming your song playing is in a short loop, it could do `while i_should_keep_running:` and the other thread does `i_should_keep_running = False` so the loop terminates.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz this worked perfectly, thank you!